# Fetching the Max Payment from Group with Payer ID in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Existing Dataframe :

```
Group        Payer_ID          status          Payment_Amount
 A              11               P                 100
 A              12               P                 100
 A              13               Q                  50
 A              14               P                 100
 A              15               P                  -
 B              11               P                  10
 B              16               Q                 150
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Group        Payer_ID              Payment_Amount
 A              11                      100
 B              16                      150
```

**if Payment amount is same it should take the first Payer_ID**

by below code i could get the max payment amount but need to fetch the respective Payer_ID as well

what changes needs to be done.?

```
Max_Payment_Amt = df.groupby('Group',as_index=False)['Payment_Amount'].max()
```

Comment: Use `idxmax` with indexing

Comment: i do have the NaN values in the Payment_Amount , df.loc[df.reset_index().groupby(['Group'])['Payment_Amount'].idxmax()]  is this the correct approoach.?

Comment: Use: `df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['Payment_Amount'], errors='coerce').groupby(df['Group']).idxmax()]`

Comment: it gives this error KeyError: '[nan] not in index'

Comment: Can you update your example to reproduce this error?